# Is it possible to use a Pi to "look" for other devices on the same network?

Tags: networking

I've used Pi's for a couple minor projects but I have been wondering if the following was possible:

**I'm hoping to utilize another Pi as part of a larger home automation project but I didn't know if it was feasible for a Raspberry Pi to essentially "listen" for particular devices to join the same local network that it is on?**

The Pi is not the DHCP server or router by any means, just another device connected to the network. Can it listen for device names? MAC addresses? Device manufacturers?

**For example:**

- Pi is connected to *MyLocalNetwork*.
- *Bob's Phone* comes within range of *MyLocalNetwork* and joins accordingly.
- Pi "sees" *Bob's Phone* and executes some sort of script, web service call, etc.
- Pi "sees" *Bob's Phone* drop off of the network and executes something else.
- Pi "sees" a *guest* device with Apple as the manufacturer and responds accordingly.

Those are just some basic examples but I'm not aware of anything that passively listens for other devices on the network.

**Is something like this possible?**

Thanks.

Comment: I know that programs like `arpwatch` exist, but is it possible to customize it so that it either sends customized emails/events?

Comment: `avahi` is a zeroconf protocol which allows device discovery. I don't know if it enables notification of connected/disconnected devices. I use `netatalk` (which uses avahi) on my Pis. It lets you use SHARENAME.local to get the IP of an available device e.g. `ping raspberrypi.local`. You could certainly poll for known/expected devices.

Comment: Is this wifi, etherlink or both?

Comment: @Bex - I'd like it to be able to recognize certain wifi devices. Connecting the Pi to ethernet would be more reliable but it could sit on wifi also.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the wireshark (GUI based) and the tshark (console) packages.

They both listen to traffic in promiscuous mode.

If they can see the data you are wanting to capture then craft your own version (it's not hard, I have done so myself).

Comment: Are there any performance issues with having it **always** listening?

Comment: There are bound to be, but from memory they were insignificant for my usage.  Looking back at the code it was four years ago and was harder than I remembered.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it may be to use a packet sniffer to watch for the BOOTP/DHCP request the device makes when it attempts to find a DHCP server.  Here's sample output from tcpdump:

```
08:31:01.505978 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from fd:63:9a:a2:33:16 (oui Unknown), length 314
```

This doesn't work so well when talking about wired devices connected to a switch, but for a home wireless network it should work just fine.

Also, to identify that as Bob's phone it helps if you already know that the MAC is fd:63:9a:a2:33:16

Arpwatch is probably a better way to do it.  It uses the same pcap library that tcpdump does to capture packets, and only looks for ARPs.  It logs new MAC/IP pairings, and can be configured to send e-mails.  The first time it runs, all pairings are new to it, so you'll probably get reports on several devices.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to do with wifi, then [kismet](https://www.kismetwireless.net/) is your very bestest friend indeed. You will be able to see the devices, when they connect, what they connect to, regardless of whether it is your own device or your neighbour's or your neighbour's cat's uncle's wireless necklace.

Answer (score 0):

Since I use my Pi as the router with `isc-dhcp-server`, I run a script to watch the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` file. For IPv6 environments `radvd` can be monitored, and if your environment have an abundance of Apple devices you can also use `avahi-daemon` to do this.